# Telerik: Generated SQL is different from sample project

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using Progress® Kendo UI® Grid for ASP.NET MVC to show data from categories table

Generated SQL code is different on Telerik sample application and my application
(Note: Telerik(2017.1.223.545) and .net framework(4.5.1) all versions are same in both projects)

Why SQL is generated differently in my application? I want my application to generate in the same way to fix the performance issue in some other project which has huge data.

My Application:

```
public ActionResult ApplicationUserRole_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            NorthwindEntities context = new NorthwindEntities();
            context.Categories.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json("nothing");                  
        }
```

My Application (Generated SQL):

```
2019-08-20 12:46:22,320 [54] INFO RollingFileDBAppender - SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[Picture] AS [Picture]
    FROM [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[CategoryID] ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Example:

```
public ActionResult Paging_Categories([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var northwind = new SampleEntities();
            northwind.Categories.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json("nothing");
        }
```

Example(Generated SQL):

```
2019-08-20 12:19:10,952 [26] INFO Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.SampleEntities+<>c line 25 - SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[Picture] AS [Picture]
    FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], [Extent1].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], [Extent1].[Picture] AS [Picture], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[CategoryID] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[CategoryID] ASC
```

Comment: I would check the Kendo UI configuration for anything that might be different such as compatibility for the SQL Server version. The Example generated SQL looks like something that would be generated for SQL Server 2008 which does not support the OFFSET/FETCH. Realistically both would be equatable.

Comment: @StevePy, Thanks for your input, In my case the query with row number is very fast compared to OFFSET/FETCH.(Note: my actual query is more complex and there is huge data in the table. I provided above query as an equivalent example). I have opened a ticket with Telerik team and I  will update this once I hear from them.

Comment: Offset/Fetch should be notably faster than a RowNum approach. I would suspect that your two scenarios are somehow running two completely different queries that are hiding either an indexing/execution plan issue, or you might be facing something like lazy loading. Have you run a profiler against the DB while that grid populates to capture all queries, then tested the query execution plan? It's hard to  give advice on apple-to-apple comparisons when the question examples are oranges. :)

Comment: @StevePy i was wrong, entity framework versions are not same in both projects, that is the reason generated sql is different.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework used is different in both projects.
For some reason performance is faster in our web application when I use Entity framework version 6.0.0

EF is generating SQL differently in different versions.

```
Entity Framework - 6.0.0

SELECT TOP (15) 
    [Extent1].[EmpId] AS [EmpId], 
    [Extent1].[Age] AS [Age], 
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent1].[Lastname] AS [Lastname]
    FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[EmpId] AS [EmpId], [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], [Extent1].[Lastname] AS [Lastname], [Extent1].[Age] AS [Age], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[EmpId] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[EmpId] ASC

Entity Framework - 6.1.3

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[EmpId] AS [EmpId], 
    [Extent1].[Age] AS [Age], 
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent1].[Lastname] AS [Lastname]
    FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[EmpId] ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY 

Entity Framework - 6.2.0

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[EmpId] AS [EmpId], 
    [Extent1].[Age] AS [Age], 
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent1].[Lastname] AS [Lastname]
    FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[EmpId] ASC)
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY
```